# Accessing previous state within a useDispatch method

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

How do I access previous state inside the callback function in react? Because once I access `data` it is always returning an initial state version, since I use `useEffect` only on mount

```
const data = useSelector(({ state }) => state.data);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(_ => {
    dataService.loadData().then(resp => {
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_DATA', payload: resp.data });
    });
}, []);

const addData = newData => {
    dataService.addData(newData).then(_ => {
        // need the up to date state here for data
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_DATA', payload: [newData, ...data] })
    });
}

return <>
    <button onClick={_ => addData({ name: "new name" })}></button>
    {data.map(elem => <div>{elem.name}</div>)}
</>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, digging through the stackoverflow and reading many react articles I found out that it is not possible to access the up to date value of state within the callback function with `useEffect` being called only once at mount.

Though, it is not a problem if you are using **class component**.

For **functional components**, you need to use `dispatch` function, which has an access to the current state. So to update my data properly, I used the next code:

```
const addData = newData => {
    dispatch(addDataDispatch(newData));
}
```

In your reducer:

```
export const addDataDispatch = newData => {
   return (dispatch, getState) => {
       const {state: {data}} = getState();
       if (data.includes(newData)) return;
       dataService.addData(newData).then(_ => {
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_DATA', payload: [newData, ...data] })
    });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not thinking about Redux correctly. You access the "previous" state in the reducer function. It's actually the current state, but the reducer function is a function of state and action, i.e. (state, action) => nextState.

The reducer function is the place to access the state you are trying to update.

Example:

```
const initialState = {
  ... other state properties ...
  data: [],
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    ... other cases ...

    case SET_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: [action.payload, ...data],
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The `addData` handler then just dispatches the action with the `newData` in the payload.

```
const addData = newData => {
  dataService.addData(newData)
    .then(_ => {
      dispatch({ type: 'SET_DATA', payload: newData })
    });
};
```

If you need to differentiate between ***loading*** the data and ***adding*** to it with regards to how it's handled and updates state, then I suggest using separate action types, `SET_DATA` and `ADD_DATA` for example.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but still I wondering why is that `data` inside the callback function always equals to the one in initial state? Why it's value doesn't contain the up to date state's value?

Comment: What if I need to check whether `data` contains some elements before updating state?

Comment: Does that mean that react hooks support access to the state only within the `dispatch` function?

Comment: @LabLab Does it *always* return the initial `data` value, or is it just an update behind? It isn't exactly clear from the code you've shared why you may be seeing any stale enclosures over `data`. If you need to check whether `data` contains some elements before updating state you can do this in the reducer where you have both the current state ***and*** the action payload. I don't quite follow your last question, but I'm inclined to say no, there are several ways to access redux state.